# How to embed an RTMP stream on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video-streaming, rtmp

I need to embed an rtmp stream that i'm hosting on my computer with nginx. I searched thoroughly but have not found a working solution, and i'm a little bit confused with livestream.flv and it's purpose.

I tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="swfobject.js"></script>
<title>Stream</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mediaspace">This text will be replaced</div>

<script>
    var so = new SWFObject('player.swf','mpl','470','290','9');
    so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
    so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
    so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
    so.addVariable('file','livestream.flv');
    so.addVariable('autostart','true');
    so.addVariable('streamer','rtmp://192.168.1.151:1935/live');
    so.write('mediaspace');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

with no luck. "This text will be replaced" never got replaced.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Have you tried: https://github.com/Streamedian/html5_rtsp_player/wiki/HTML5-RTSP-Player?

Comment: No one uses flash these days, it's pretty much dead

Comment: Tried it, shows an empty player

Comment: Where did you find `player.swf`? Also is just this RTMP link enough to send a working stream : `rtmp://192.168.1.151:1935/live`? You can test via online players (Wowza site).